# Rails ActiveStorage: link to cloudfront

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, rails-activestorage

I have a Rails 5.2 app hosted in Amazon Elasticbeanstalk. I have a model with images stored in s3 via ActiveStorage. I have configured Cloudfront to serve images from s3 bucket.
I need to make the last step: how can I redirect images & image variants to cloudfront instead of s3?
Currently my code in views is:

```
- @item.images.each do |image|
    .item-image.col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-xs-12
      = link_to url_for(image), "data-toggle": "lightbox", "data-gallery": "item" do
        = image_tag image.variant(resize: "400x400"), class: "img-fluid", title: @item.title, alt: @item.title
```

It works, but it loads all the images from s3.
I suppose there should be some config where I can specify my cloudfront endpoint. But googling din't help :(

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, Active Storage doesn’t support public file serving yet.

Comment: Are you planning to include CDN support in Rails 6? Thanks